# É possivel encurtar o caminho dos arquivos .h incluidos pelo arquivo .pri?

Tags: qt

Estou tentando separar a minha aplicação de uma pequena lib aberta que criei, então coloquei a os arquivos no `.pri` e inclui no `.pro`, a estrutura da pasta ficou assim:

```
c:/projetos/
├── minhalib
│   ├── minhalib.pri
│   ├── foo
│   |   ├── foo.cpp
│   |   └── foo.h
│   └── bar
│       ├── bar.cpp
│       └── bar.h
|
└── aplicativo
    ├── aplicativo.pro
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── mainwindow.cpp
    └── mainwindow.h
```

No aplicativo .pro eu tenho isto:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = aplicacao
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
           mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

include($PWD/../../minhalib/minhalib.pri)
```

E no `minhalib/foo.pri` eu tenho isto:

```
SOURCES  += $$PWD/foo/foo.cpp \
            $$PWD/bar/bar.cpp

HEADERS  += $$PWD/foo/foo.h \
            $$PWD/bar/bar.h
```

No `main.cpp` eu chamei assim:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "../minhalib/bar/bar.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Bar bar;
    bar.test();

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Note que eu inclui assim `#include "../minhalib/bar/bar.h"`, mas eu gostaria de incluir de maneira mais simples, algo como:

```
#include <bar/bar>
#include <foo/foo>
```

Ou:

```
#include "bar/bar.h"
#include "foo/foo.h"
```

Como posso fazer isso configurando no `.pri`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver basta usar o `INCLUDEPATH +=`, no caso especifico basta apontar o caminho com `$PWD`

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

SOURCES  += $$PWD/foo/foo.cpp \
            $$PWD/bar/bar.cpp

HEADERS  += $$PWD/foo/foo.h \
            $$PWD/bar/bar.h
```

Assim o compilador passa a reconhecer os caminhos assim:

```
#include "bar/bar.h"
#include "foo/foo.h"
```

Uma dica do colega @Bacco para encurtar mais é usar definir o caminho completo diretamente no `INCLUDEPATH +=`, assim por exemplo:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/foo \
               $$PWD/bar \

SOURCES  += $$PWD/foo/foo.cpp \
            $$PWD/bar/bar.cpp

HEADERS  += $$PWD/foo/foo.h \
            $$PWD/bar/bar.h
```

Então no basta incluir assim:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
```

Precisa ter um cuidado extra de verificar se não existem arquivos de mesmo nome nos diretórios indicados